# binance.exceptions.BinanceAPIException: APIError(code=-1022): Signature for this request is not valid

Tags: python, binance

I am having issues accessing my Binance account information via API in Python. It always gives the APIError Exception but I am able to ping the exchange and get candlestick data successfully. I read through the API documentation and made sure that the API key is valid and I don't think I am missing anything.

`binance_client = BinanceClient(api_key=api_key, api_secret=api_secret)
 print(binance_client.get_account(recvWindow=60000000))`

Answer (score 3):

If someone still needs it, I created an example python script that returns your balances.
It includes a valid signature.
https://github.com/thirstygerry/binance-python

Comment: Hello! While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: The example ran as it still gives the same error.

Answer (score 0):

maximum value for recvWindow is 60000.